# DNS query with winsock fails

Tags: c++, windows, dns, winsock

I understand winsock has gethostbyname for this. But I need to debug for embedded application and first I try the code on Windows. Here is a my code:
Hide   Expand   Copy Code

```
sockaddr_in dns_addr;
int dns_size = sizeof(dns_addr);
ZeroMemory(&dns_addr, dns_size);
dns_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dns_addr.sin_port = htons(53);
dns_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8");

SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

char msg[] = {
    0x12, 0x34,         // ID
    0x01, 0x00,         // QR ... RCODE
    0x00, 0x01,         // QDCOUNT
    0x00, 0x00,         // ANCOUNT
    0x00, 0x00,         // NSCOUNT
    0x00, 0x00,         // ARCOUNT
    0x03,
    0x77, 0x77, 0x77,       // www
    0x03,
    0x74, 0x75, 0x74,       // tut
    0x02,
    0x62, 0x79,         // by
    0x00,
    0x00, 0x01,         // TYPE_A
    0x00, 0x01          // CLASS_IN
};
int msg_size = sizeof(msg);
int iSendOk = sendto(out, msg, msg_size, 0, (sockaddr*)&dns_addr, dns_size);

if (iSendOk != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    char bufstr[100];
    sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    int dest_addr_size = sizeof(dest_addr);
    int iReceived = recvfrom(out, bufstr, 100, 0,(sockaddr*)&dest_addr, &dest_addr_size);
}

closesocket(out);
```

And this code freezes when recvfrom function is execution. The function is executed with an infinite loop and never returns. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Then your socket is not receiving a reply. Have you tried watching it in Wireshark? Wireshark is a good tool for debugging network programs.

Comment: How can Wireshark help to find why recvfrom is freezzing?

Comment: @Yaumen Wireshark can help you validate whether a reply is actually be sent from the DNS or not. If you don't see a reply on your network at all, then your request is likely malformed and the server is ignoring it (Wireshark can also parse your request and show its components to you so you can determine if it is malformed or not), or the reply is being blocked, such as by a firewall/router. If you do see a reply, but your code is not receiving it, then your socket code is likely setup wrong.

Comment: @Yaumen On a side note: "*I understand winsock has gethostbyname for this*" - `gethostbyname()` has been deprecated for a long time now, use `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: You really should try to use a library to do DNS operations and not build packets by hand. You are bound to hit so many problems otherwise...